# Why are these questions closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, site-specific

Refs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060671/difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa

I actually need an answer to this question.  No, I am not asking from the [Gorilla v. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) perspective.

**IF** you think these question should still both be closed, please offer a way to ask differently that will not result in closure.

The first one: Read the user comments.  They are intelligent and make good points.

The second one: Has over 200 up-votes.

Comment: These are both open-ended questions. That's why they have been closed. The OP is asking too general a question, instead of focusing on the specifics of their needs, in both questions.

Comment: I read the comments. I see `How it this qst not constructive? Some people need to get a life.` and `Given that this is the top google result for 'openjdk vs oracle jdk' this question should be migrated or re-opened.`. I don't agree these are good points for reopening the question. If anything, the latter could be seen as an argument for *deleting* it so it stops polluting the Google index.... *(ducks)*

Comment: As for asking them in a constructive manner - figure out why you need to know the differences - focus on the issue you are trying to solve and explain your research and what you have looked at already (explaining why you were not able to determine the difference, for example).

Comment: *"IF you think these question should still both be closed, please offer a way to ask differently that will not result in closure."* ... if it's differences/pros and cons/evaluations you're looking for, you can phrase it any which way you want, but it's (by now) not a good fit for the site.

Comment: `The first one: Read the user comments. They are intelligent and make good points. The second one: Has over 200 up-votes.` Why does that matter? They're both not constructive. Comments and upvotes make no difference.

Comment: A question should not be 'intelligent and make good points". This isn't a forum.

Comment: Notice that the answer to the question is little more than "here are a few blog posts and a link to the FAQ." If your whole argument is that this is appropriate as the top Google result- why shouldn't those links just be top results themselves?

Answer (score 11):

These questions are closed for the following reasons:

- No objectively correct, *complete* answer is possible.  You could have 10 people post ten answers with ten different differences. Who is correct?  Who's to say who is correct?
- Open ended: When is the question definitively answered? Ever?
- Doesn't address a specific problem.  If we allow these types of questions, where does it end? Should I use Windows XP or Windows Vista to develop apps? Should I use CPython or regular Python when writing python programs? [Should I use Canvas or write native apps](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5663031)?

We can't answer what you *should* do. Only you can answer that. The best thing that these answers can provide is a list of reasons on either side, and that's going to invite debate, and a lot of it.

We're a culture [that gets worked up over where we put braces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line). How do you *think* a question about something more substantive is going to go?

That's why they're closed. They have the propensity to devolve, there's no 'right' answer, and in short, they're bikeshed questions.  Everyone loves bikeshed questions because they can answer them, but they drive away experts.

In order to get these questions re-opened, you'd have to do major surgery on them (in short, probably impossible due to the history surrounding the question).

For instance:

> I've been creating a project using the Oracle Java SDK (Insert relevant information about the project here), and I've noticed that when I tried to run the project using the OpenJDK, *X*, *Y*, and *Z* happened (with specific technical information about X, Y, and Z).
>
> I'd like to port this project over to OpenJDK (With reasons included), and I'm worried that X, Y, and Z will cause problems for me:  Do X, Y, and Z, have a measurable impact on whether I should port my code?  Are these SDKs meant to be compatible?
>
> How do I fix problems X,Y, and Z when I port the code over to OpenJDK?)

(Everything in parentheses should be filled out with actual information).

These questions are from a time when we didn't realize what would happen if we allowed these questions to run free.  Now we know, and as such, we close them (or try to).

Those questions are great comparison questions, but as you've probably noticed, the Stack Overflow system doesn't handle comparisons well.  You can have 100 different comparisons and 100 different answers, and none of them would be a complete answer.

I think this is why [Slant.co](http://slant.co/) was created.  They do comparisons really well. I'd suggest asking this question there and see what sort of response you get.